# Metalanguage to describe expressing an idea in many different ways

Tags: terminology, lexical-semantics, meaning, phrases

I am looking for a term to describe expressing an idea in many different forms yet the meaning remains the same in each rendition.

An example of this:

*The Australians, Australians, the Australian people, the people of Australia, Australia's people etc.*

All the phrases above virtually express the same thing yet they are all different, lexico-grammatically speaking.

Thus, the term ***synonym*** does not work here. I have also come across the idea of ***periphrasis*** but that also has a restrictive definition that does not include my example.

Comment: Why does synonym or synonymous not work?

Answer (score 1):

They are different 'linguistic forms' pointing to the same referent, so the term 'periphrases' (generated through grammatical transformations) seems the correct one. Instead, Frege used the term 'sense' (german *Sinn*) to describe cases such as 'disciple of Plato' and 'tutor of Alexander' to refer to Aristotle, intended as 'different ways of presenting itself' (german 'Art von Gegenbenseins'), though one from a cognitive POV would name them 'conceptualizations'.

Answer (score 0):

In translation studies, I encountered the term *variation* for this phenomenon. It is a pretty generic term with lots of other uses, but I don't know a better one.

For usage of the term see, e.g., the [VARTRA (Variation in Translation)](http://hdl.handle.net/11858/00-246C-0000-0023-8CDB-A) corpus.